# Why isn't the TARDIS sopping wet at the end of "The Doctor Falls"?

Tags: doctor-who

Obviously, spoilers follow for the season 10 finale. (Even the question title is slightly spoiler-y, but it can't be helped.)

OK, so

> Heather

finds Bill and turns her into, well, whatever it is that

> Heather has become, which seems to involve copious amounts of water.

Indeed, even as the Cyberman-shell is still in the process of toppling, we see that Bill is

> dripping water, same as Heather.

Then, somehow, they're in the TARDIS, and the above-mentioned rescuer is piloting it, and The Doctor (or his body) is lying on the ground... which is completely

> dry. Neither Bill nor Heather are dripping.

Why not?

Comment: Heather says something about being able to manipulate matter at the atomic level.  Even says she can literally recreate Bill if wanted.  So I guess she can turn off the water when she wants.

Answer (score 1):

Heather is basically formed of what the doctor calls "intelligent motor oil" left behind from a very powerful spaceship* (see season 10, episode 1).

That "motor oil" is intelligent and can form itself into any form both solid and liquid (I guess it's made up of tiny nano bots).

So to answer your question, there's no water involved so nothing can get wet, just tiny nanobots.

<sub>* That we haven't seen yet, and is possibly more powerful than the TARDIS</sub>

Comment: Having re-watching ep1 it could well be that the oil is the spaceship

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing two things

> Heather converted Bill into whatever she is now. This way Bill was no longer a Cyberman. Once that was done, they could then return to floor 0 and retrieve the Tardis (Heather has already shown herself able to effortlessly transcend space and time, which means Bill can do the same). She also transports the Doctor to the TARDIS, presumably the same way she transports herself. I can only presume the Doctor isn't wet because they pulled the "water" parts of themselves back. In other words, they don't convert the Doctor as well. Once at the TARDIS, she then drives it ("I'm the pilot. I can fly anything."). So the TARDIS isn't wet because it was driven.

Comment: Um, eh? The TARDIS should be wet because Bill and Heather should be dripping "water" all over it, not because they somehow converted it into Heather Species.

Comment: @Martha - Heather and Bill don't always need to be wet as shown in the episode "The Pilot" Heather could control whether she is wet or not. Bill was not wet when Heather transformed her. I assume when they travelled up to floor 0 to get to the Tardis they became a dry species.

Comment: @Martha There's no evidence that items she transports become wet. It's not something we've seen on screen